# Get php website response in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a php website that returns YES or NO upon request.
For example

www.test.com/test.php?variable=test1
will return me YES
and www.test.com/test.php?variable=test2
will return me NO

I am trying to get this response into an Objective-C application I am creating but I have no luck up to now.
Here is my code

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/test.php?variable=test1"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    NSMutableData *receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"This is the response: %@", strData);
}else {
 }
```

Can anybody help me on that? is there any other way to do it? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: When you say that you "have no luck up to now", what is happening?  Crash, "This is the response: " never prints?   Do you have the delegate set up to receive the data as it comes in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
        {
            [receivedData appendData:data];
        // declre receivedData as a property of the class(in xxx.m)
            NSError *error=nil;
            NSDictionary *result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                                  NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            NSLog("%@", result);
    //do whatever you want...

           //the result dictionary is a JSON object and you can use it as KVC(key-value-coding) rules  
 }
```

If your app targets iOS 5 just use this code to your xxx.m file under the method you create the request. And if you want to use it in some other versions of iOS, Take a look JSON parser frameworks..

Comment: can you please elaborate on that? Because I am trying to use it but I get a lot of errors

Comment: in your... .h file declare a property for receivedData and sysnthesyze it in .m.. And your receivedData is nsmutabledata, declare it as nsmutabledictionary(or just nes dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting up your connection correctly. However, you then have to catch the data in the NSURLConnection Delegate methods documented in the `NSURLConnection.h` file:

```
@protocol NSURLConnectionDataDelegate <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@optional
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

- (NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)request;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
                                                 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
                                         totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
@end
```

Of particular interest are `didReceiveData` and `connectionDidFinishLoading`.